# Discord Py, discord bot get message content of another bot/embed/webhook

Tags: python, discord

When ever it picks up message content from a webhook/bot/embed it would always send a blank line/whitespace, I wanted to know if it was possible for my discord bot to see the content of these webhook/bot/embed.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == True:
        print(message.content)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Trying to get a webhook to communicate with my bot but it does not pick it up at all.

Comment: i don't think bots are able to see embeds, possibly what you could do is use the discord token of your own account or second account and use that to view the messages of the embeds. this would take a bit of reverse engineering and looking at the page requests and trying to replicate the apis.

Answer (score 1):

#### To get the embed

```py
if len(message.embeds) > 0:
    embed = message.embeds[0] #you can do embed.title to get the title and other details of the embed now
```

#### To get another bot message

```py
if message.author.bot and message.author != client.user:
    msg = message.content
```

#### To get webhook message

```py
if message.webhook_id:
    msg = message.content
```